# Which adapter to use in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, view, adapter

I have a data-model which is of type

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
```

what type of adapter should I use?... Or should I make a custom-one, and if so; what should I inherit from??

The reason it's of this type is because it's a set of feed-elements that consist of fields of strings. E.g.:
                            title: Syria bombings!
                            body: In Syria, yesterday...
                            //next feed-element...

Comment: The question is: what is it you want to implement?

Comment: I think baseadapter will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Which array adapter to use depends on what you need. 
You'll need to override it to set the textboxes.if the data is in an array already, you will probably use an arrayadapter.you can use the simple_list_item_2 to display the data.
Here's a good example:

http://sethgholson.com/2012/01/using-simple_list_item_2-with-an-arrayadapter-android/